# Combining MethodHandles.publicLookup() with Method.setAccessible(true)

Tags: java, reflection, java-8, methodhandle

I understand that `publicLookup()` is faster than a `lookup()` for public methods, and I would like to make use of that. If I was to use `MethodHandles.publicLookup().unreflect(Method)` on a `Method` which is not inherently public but I have called `setAccessible(true)` on, would it work?

Comment: Why not try it and find out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since a `Method` on which `setAccessible(true)` has been successfully invoked can be called by everyone, it can made unreflected using the `MethodHandles.publicLookup()` like with any other `Lookup` object.

After all, it’s the only way to use access override with `MethodHandle`s as `java.lang.invoke` does not offer any access override feature on its own.

The following demonstration uses  a `Field` rather than a `Method` but has an impressive result:

```
Field m = String.class.getDeclaredField("value");
m.setAccessible(true);
MethodHandle mh = MethodHandles.publicLookup().unreflectGetter(m);
char[] ch = (char[])mh.invoke("hello");
Arrays.fill(ch, '*');
System.out.println("hello");
```

Comment: ah, sadly I don't need to run that to know the output, as I've messed around with that before. however, thanks for the answer