# `MethodHandle` slower than Reflection when accessing Object

Tags: java, performance, reflection, methodhandle

I would like to call a method via reflection in the most performant way possible.

The method returns an Object.

I've implemented this using both reflection and MethodHandles, I was expecting MethodHandle to be faster - but that's not what I'm seeing (~20-40% slower).

Take the following JMH benchmark:

```
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 200, time = 10, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class AccessorBenchmark {
    private static final Object[] EMPTY_ARGS = new Object[0];

    private POJO source;
    private Method method;
    private MethodHandle methodHandle;
    private MethodHandle methodHandleModifiedReturnType;

    @Setup
    public void setup() throws ReflectiveOperationException {
        source = new POJO();

        method = source.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getNumber");
        
        methodHandle = MethodHandles.lookup().unreflect(method);
        methodHandleModifiedReturnType = methodHandle.asType(methodHandle.type().changeReturnType(Number.class));
    }

    @Benchmark
    public Number reflection() throws Throwable {
        return (Number) method.invoke(source, EMPTY_ARGS);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public Number methodHandle() throws Throwable {
        return (Number) methodHandle.invoke(source);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public Number methodHandleInvokeExact() throws Throwable {
        return  (Number) methodHandleModifiedReturnType.invokeExact(source);
    }

    public class POJO {
        private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

        public AtomicInteger getNumber() {
            return counter;
        }
    }
}
```

The following result is returned with Java 17:

```
Benchmark                                     Mode   Cnt   Score    Error   Units
AccessorBenchmark.methodHandle                avgt  1000   2.856 ±  0.004   ns/op
AccessorBenchmark.methodHandleInvokeExact     avgt  1000   2.359 ±  0.003   ns/op
AccessorBenchmark.reflection                  avgt  1000   2.017 ±  0.002   ns/op
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure it will change but your `methodHandle()` and `methodHandleInvokeExact()` both returns  Number, which imply a cast from `Number` to `Object`: you are not exactly testing the same thing.

Comment: Note: reflection was reimplemented to use method handles in [Java 18](https://openjdk.org/jeps/416)

Comment: Didn’t you ask this earlier?

Comment: @DaveNewton that was about primitives - where it turned out my benchmark was wrong and the code was right. But this scenario the benchmark is right (I think!) and I still have an unexpected result.

Comment: @NoDataFound good spot, fixed. Same results though.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to call a method by reflection in the first place?

Comment: The difference between these times is not even 1 _nanosecond_. Does it really matter? Choose the API that provides what you need and is easier to use. Plus, as noted, reflection uses method handles under the hood in Java 18+.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your method handles `static final` so that they can be constant folded (apparently).

See this article [Java Reflection, but much faster](https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2018/01/09/JavaReflectionButMuchFaster.html#_static_methodhandles_update_on_2018_01_11), which explores reflection vs. method handle performance as you want.

Comment: Thanks - I'm aware `static final` would help, but in my application they are instance fields of an object so this wouldn't help. I'd still expect it to be faster than reflection though?

Comment: I did find this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937872/combining-methodhandles-publiclookup-with-method-setaccessibletrue) which used `publicLookup()` instead. I'm unsure if `setAccessible(true)` makes any difference or not.

Comment: Does just `final` make any difference?

Comment: That’s also a really interesting link, Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

See answer by scrhartley. Two additional benchmarks for direct call, and with lookup method handle directly as static final field (not via reflection) shows better results:

```
/** Test POJO directly */
@Benchmark
public Number direct() throws Throwable {
    return source.getNumber();
}
private static final Lookup     LOOKUP = MethodHandles.lookup();
/** Lookup details of an instance method handle on a Java class */
static MethodHandle findInstanceMH(Class<?> cls, String callback, MethodType methodType) {
    try {
        return LOOKUP.findVirtual(cls, callback, methodType);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new Error("Not found callback: "+callback);
    }
}
private static final MethodHandle MH  = findInstanceMH(POJO.class, "getNumber", MethodType.methodType(AtomicInteger.class));
private static final MethodHandle MHN = MH.asType(MH.type().changeReturnType(Number.class));

/** Test static final MethodHandle obtained by MH lookup */
@Benchmark
public Number methodHandleNormal() throws Throwable {
    return  (Number) MHN.invokeExact(source);
}
```

With the new benchmarks you should see method handle version much quicker than reflection and compares well with direct call:

```
Benchmark                                  Mode   Cnt   Score   Error  Units
AccessorBenchmark.direct                   avgt  1000   4.925 ± 0.047  ns/op
AccessorBenchmark.methodHandle             avgt  1000  10.327 ± 0.066  ns/op
AccessorBenchmark.methodHandleInvokeExact  avgt  1000   9.478 ± 0.066  ns/op
AccessorBenchmark.methodHandleNormal       avgt  1000   5.063 ± 0.054  ns/op
AccessorBenchmark.reflection               avgt  1000  17.477 ± 0.116  ns/op
```